# Scraping Jira and entering it in Google Sheet (filling cells

Tags: python-2.7, jira, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need help figuring out how to finish my script.

So far I can get the info I need from Jira and I now know the basics of entering stuff into google sheets but my problem is when I try to combine the too.

If I just run the scraper for Jira I get 50 different values but when add the googlesheet code it only enters the last value out of the 50.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

I am using python and working with PYCHARM.

Thanks!

```
# coding=utf-8

from jira.client import JIRA
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("blank", SCOPES)
connection = gspread.authorize(credentials)

options = {'server': 'https://jira.blank.com/'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('blank', 'blank'))
projects = jira.projects()

for i in jira.search_issues('filter=11152'):
print i

worksheet = connection.open("blank").sheet1

cell_list = worksheet.range('A2:A51')

for cell in cell_list:
cell.value = i

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)

print("Done updating, check the spreadsheet now")
```

Comment: Never mind I solved it
    <blink>
    for cell, x in zip(cell_list, jira.search_issues('filter=11152')):
     cell.value = x
    </blink>

Comment: for cell, x in zip(cell_list, jira.search_issues('filter=11152')): cell.value = x